# Preciso de ajuda no comando IF, ele não funciona não sei por que, ele encerra o programa quando eu escrevo FRENTE é pra ser um jogo de escrever

Tags: java, eclipse, jogos

package leitura;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[]  args) {
                 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nome;
    Random rand = new Random();
    System.out.println("Bem vindo ao jogo!  digite seu nome: ");
    nome = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("seja muito bem vindo(a) "+ nome);
    System.out.println("para qual direção você gostaria de ir? (frente)");
    String comando = in.nextLine();
    if(comando == "frente")  {
        System.out.println("você está indo para frente");
        System.out.println("Um inimigo surge das sombras, O que você ira fazer? (lutar,fugir)");
        comando = in.nextLine();
        if(comando == "lutar") {
                System.out.println("Você mata a criatura sombria, Parabéns você ganhou o jogo");
             }
        }
            
        }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para comparação de Strings você deve usar equals.

```
if (comando.equals("frente"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Na linguagem java a comparação de Strings e de outras classes é feita através do método equals().

a notação "==" serve apenas para comparar tipos primitivos (int, float, char ....), ou para no caso de objetos, comparar se as referencias dos objetos na memoria é a mesma.

Caso eu tenha confundido você, apenas entenda que String se compara utilizando o .equals, e quando você aprender programação orientada a objetos você vai entender.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
    public static void main(String[]  args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nome;
    Random rand = new Random();
    System.out.println("Bem vindo ao jogo!  digite seu nome: ");
    nome = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("seja muito bem vindo(a) "+ nome);
    System.out.println("para qual direção você gostaria de ir? (frente)");
    String comando = in.nextLine();
    if(comando.equals("frente"))  {
        System.out.println("você está indo para frente");
        System.out.println("Um inimigo surge das sombras, O que você ira fazer? (lutar,fugir)");
        comando = in.nextLine();
        if(comando.equals("lutar")) {
            System.out.println("Você mata a criatura sombria, Parabéns você ganhou o jogo");
        }
    }
```